# How can I display an error message in a form while using php and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, forms, validation, if-statement

// What I am Trying to do is to use php and insert my subscribers of Websites In A database first here is

// my html code

```
<center>
  <form action="members.php" method="post">
    <h1 class="title-4">Subscribe For Our Latest Updates</h1>

    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Enter Your Full Name">

    <div class="error-name" style="display:none">
      <p>Please Enter Your Name </p>
    </div>

    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter Your E-mail" >

    <div class="error-email" style="display:none">
      <p>Please Enter a Password Password must be greater than 7 characters  </p>
    </div>

   <input type="submit" name="submit" id="sub" class="name-sub email-sub" value="Subscribe">  

  </form>
</center>

<div class="sub-pop">
  <center>
    <h1 class="title-5">
      &#9733;Thanks For Subscribing &#9733;
    </h1>
  </center>
</div>
<script src="home.js"></script>
```

// here is the php Code in members.php

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

  $connection=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','lolovers');

  $name  = $_POST['name'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];

  $query = "INSERT INTO subscribers(name,email)";
  $query .= "VALUES ('$name','$email')";

  $subscribe=mysqli_query($connection,$query);

  header('Location:home.php');
}
```

// This is the code to insert my user name and emails in my data base php admin

// here is my  javascript that I use to validate my information

```
    // Pop up form for subscribers javascript code
const popUp      = document.querySelector('.title-5');
const name       = document.querySelector('#name');
const email      = document.querySelector('#email');
const subscribe  = document.querySelector('#sub');
const errorName  = document.querySelector('.error-name')
const errorEmail = document.querySelector('.error-email')

subscribe.addEventListener('click',subscription());

function subscription(e) {

  if(name.value==="") {
    errorName.style.display = "block"
  }
  else if (email.value==="") {
    errorEmail.style.display = "block"
  }
  else if (name.value && email.value==="") {
    errorName.style.display  = "block"
    errorEmail.style.display = "block"
    e.preventDefault()
  }
  else {
    popUp.style.display="block"
  }
}
```

// The reason why I am using php and javascript is because I have a hard time to display an error message

in php so instead of validating using php I use javascript to validate my form information and I use php

insert the data in php myadmin. The error messages I want to display is in

```
<div class="error-name" style="display:none">
    <p>Please Enter Your Name </p>
  </div>
```

// I want to use javascript so that when some one does not enter his name this div section display under

the form

```
 <div class="error-email" style="display:none">
    <p>Please Enter a Password Password must be greater than 7 characters  </p>
</div>
```

// the same thing above I want this div section to display when some one does not enter his email

//somehow my javascript does not work properly when i try to refresh the page my div sections display

automatically even though I did not enter any information it just displays. it even display my thank you

section

```
<div class="sub-pop">
   <center><h1 class="title-5">
   &#9733;Thanks For Subscribing &#9733;
   </h1></center>
</div>
```

// I also want my php code to not insert the data in the database when the information is not valid

Comment: why email must be a **password** wiith lenght of 7 chars  min ?

Comment: Sorry my bad I typed by accident there is no need I just want it to display the message of someone did not write an email

Answer (score 0):

you unnecessarily complicate the task, html5 natively offers this kind of control, without having to add any line of additional code unless you want to customize them.

Just add the `required` attribute on these fields

```css
form {
  display: table;
  margin: 1em auto;   /* horizontal centering */
  padding: .7em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
input, button {
  display: block;
  margin:.5em;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<form action="members.php" method="post">
  <h4>Subscribe For Our Latest Updates</h4>

  <input type="text"  name="name"   placeholder="Enter Your Full Name" required >
  <input type="email" name="email"  placeholder="Enter Your E-mail"    required >

  <button type="submit">Subscribe</button>
</form>
```

there is many tutorials on the web to explain this.
You also get precise information on MDN -> https://developer.mozilla.org